# What causes of action would legitimate suing an all girls private school in Toronto for $5.5M, and $38M?

Tags: education, ontario

On [Dec 1 2019](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/toronto/bullying-lawsuit-1.5398414), lawyer Andrew Rogerson sued Havergal College for $5.5M. Angela Salvatore was a partner at his law firm, and was representing Rogerson and Rogerson's daughter who attended Havergal.

On [May 11 2020](https://www.toronto.com/news/havergal-private-school-failed-to-prevent-relentless-bullying-against-girl-38-million-lawsuit-claims/article_bc09e8fd-1892-56c5-80fd-a872954acc02.html), Andrew Rogerson and Angela Salvatore sued Havergal College for $38M, for another mother and student.

How exactly are these lofty quantums calculated? Are they legitimate? I never knew that damages for psychiatric injury can amount to millions!

I am not in any way affiliated or connected with these lawyers or this school, or any of its subsidiaries or its affiliates. My husband and I found these news article when we were researching schools for our daughter. Havergal is an all girls private school in Toronto, Canada.

Comment: "Bullying" is how the headlines in the stories cited describe it, or more rightly, failure to prevent bullying or failure to address it.

Answer (score 1):

### [Harrassment](http://hrprofessionalnow.ca/legal-words/468-new-tort-of-harassment-allows-employees-to-sue-for-damages) and Negligence

At least, those are the causes of action that spring to mind.

Please bear in mind that the amount the plaintiff seeks may be as much as they can provide evidence to support. The amount they [get](https://cdn.ymaws.com/www.ccla-abcc.ca/resource/resmgr/pp-civlit/2020damagescompendium.pdf) is typically much less.